# Windows Phone 8.1 appbar background image or gradient brush not visible?

Tags: background-image, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

While porting my existing [windows store 8.1 app](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/jee-mains/5dceeda7-f9ec-4fec-9808-ea08250fe415) to windows phone 8.1 I am facing difficulty in commandbar's background. as you can see in the apps screenshot
When I set it to solid color its working fine and showing in emulator and device but when I set it to an image background as my windows Desktop app appbar becomes blank.
Even tried adding a gradient instead of image

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True"  >
        <CommandBar.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8D8787" Offset="0.3"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC9242B"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </CommandBar.Background>           
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

still its showing blank how can I fix it. 
2) Even the Tapped events of appbar are not working have to convert them into clicked events. Is clicked the right event?